# Facebook->api("/me") raises "CurlException: 3: No URL set!"

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I have an iframe page tab facebook app that, for some users on some pages, raises a "CurlException: 3: No URL set!" exception when calling $facebook->api("/me").

Here is the code :

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = APPID;
$config['secret'] = APPSECRET;
$config['cookie'] = true;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if (isset($_GET['tk'])&&($_GET['tk']!="")){
$_SESSION['appat'] = $_GET['tk'];
}

if ($_SESSION['appat']!="")
$access_token = $_SESSION['appat'];

$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);       

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        trace("exception $e");
    }
}
```

NOTE : The access token is given by the Javascript sdk as a GET variable as received on the app home page and I store it into a session variable for further uses.

Comment: Forgot to mention the following warning showing up in those cases :

"Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in (...)/base_facebook.php on line 963"

It looks to me like a bug in the Facebook api where it tries to set a value for option CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE that does not exist in the curl_setopt() official doc (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Now that lines using CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE as curl_opt are commented, I get the following exception instead :
"CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:2110:3f07:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable"

It seems to me like there's a Facebook server somewhere that causes the problem. Don't know if that's make sense or how I should deal with this, though.

Answer (score 0):

by problems with IPV6 you should have included the following line in your facebook api.

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4;
```

however this alternative only works with version 5.3 of php largest

solution:

```
if((phpversion()>= 5.3))
{ 
   Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4; 
}
```